# Select rows from table with date after today

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my MySQL database with, say, following fields:

`id, client, date`

the type is:

`id -> int(20) unsigned, client -> varchar(100), date -> varchar(20)`

as data example:

`'234', 'John Doe', '08/13'`

`'112', 'Joanna Doe', '08/12'`

I want to select all records that are after today's date as mm/YY (09/13)
Can somebody help please?

Comment: After todays? Where you see here day mm/YY '08/12' ?

Comment: 'date' as varchar(20)? Set column type as datetime. It will make your task easy.

Comment: in "data examples": '08/13' and '08/12' (in this case if I can select that I will get only '08/13' because today is '09/13' and is what I need)

Comment: @AvinashT. I already have my data in this format as "varchar(20)" and 'mm/YY' and this type of output is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from yourtable
where
  (year(curdate()) % 1000 < substring_index(date, '/', -1))
  or
  (year(curdate()) % 1000 = substring_index(date, '/', -1)
   and month(curdate()) < substring_index(date, '/', 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use MySQL's str_to_date function.

```
select * from table where str_to_date(date,'%m/%Y') > sysdate;
```

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
select date from mytable where str_to_date(date,'%m/%Y') > str_date('01/13','%m/%Y');
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the job: mysql> select `date` from `mytable` where str_to_date(date,'%m/%Y') > '01/13' limit 10;
+-------+
| date  |
+-------+
| 08/10 | 
| 10/11 | 
| 10/13 | 
| 04/12 | 
| 07/11 | 
| 12/11 | 
| 03/11 | 
| 05/10 | 
| 02/12 | 
| 02/13 | 
+-------+
10 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)